# ng-table with pagination and grouping

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I am working with ng-table and facing issue with grouping. The count attribute indicates number of groups per page.

```
this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
  count:2,
  group: "country"
}, {
  dataset: list
});
}
```

Is there a way to implement pagination based on number of rows per page instead of groups per page?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done for whole table as well as only for grouped data.

its addressed in the below issue.

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/893